# order of insert/erase statements between independent lists causing seg fault

Tags: c++, list, insert, erase

What i am implementing is a bit more complicated so i have stripped down the code and made the simplest example possible that replicates the problem:

I have lists A and B, at some point i need to move 1 element from list A to list B. This object memorizes its position (iterator) on the list that is currently on. It works perfectly well for 1 list, inserting and erasing. Nevertheless, when change list B inside an iterative cycle of list A, i found that the order in which i execute the insert and erase instructions determines if i get an seg fault. Here is the code:

```
typedef struct AO_ {
    int id; 
    list<AO_*>::iterator thispos;
} AnObject;

class MyList {
    public:

    list<AnObject*> ll;
    int sizell;

    MyList(){ sizell=0; }

    void insert(AnObject* AnObjecti){
        AnObjecti->thispos= ll.insert(ll.end(),AnObjecti);
        sizell++;
    }

    list<AnObject*>::iterator remove(AnObject* AnObjecti){
        return ll.erase(AnObjecti->thispos);
    }   

    void print(){
        cout << "contents:";
        list<AnObject*>::iterator itAux;
        for (itAux=ll.begin(); itAux!=ll.end(); itAux++)
        cout << " " << (*itAux)->id;
        cout << endl;               
    }           
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    MyList* listA= new MyList();
    MyList* listB= new MyList();
    AnObject* objAux= new AnObject(); 

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        objAux= new AnObject(); 
        objAux->id= i; 
        listA->insert(objAux);
    }

    cout << "list A:" << endl; listA->print();

    list<AnObject*>::iterator it= listA->ll.begin();
    while(it!=listA->ll.end()){
        objAux= (*it);
        if(objAux->id==2){
            //listB->insert(objAux); //***THIS CAN GO HERE (seg fault on next cycle)
            it= listA->remove(objAux);      
            listB->insert(objAux); //***OR THIS CAN GO HERE (all ok)
        }
        else
            ++it;
    }

    cout << "list A:"; listA->print();
    cout << "list B:"; listB->print();
}
```

and the output:

```
list A:
contents: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
list A:contents: 0 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
list B:contents: 2
```

I get a seg fault if exchange the instructions marked by ***
Does someone know why?

Thanks in advance
jose

Answer (score 1):

The call to `listB->insert` modifies `objAux->thispos` to refer to the new list. Then the call to `listA->remove` will try to use that iterator in its call to `list::erase`. Passing an iterator from the wrong container to `erase` gives undefined behaviour.